# Как определить силу удара при столкновении двух объектов через PhysX в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, 2d, физика

Работаю в Unity3D 5.3.4 на Windows 10.

Имеется сложное тело, состоящее из нескольких  отдельных `Rigidbody2D` и `CircleCollider2D`, которые соединены друг с другом через `SpringJoint2D`. Задача определить с какой силой ударилось тело о поверхность при падении, чтобы при ударе больше некоего значения снижать прочность и при ее снижении до 0 запустить процедуру разрушения объекта. Что для этого сделал. Добавил на каждый элемент объект фиксирующий столкновение:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{

    float power = collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude;
    if (power >= dangerPower)
    {
        state.SetPower(power);
    }
}
```

на каждом шаге определяется сила удара при столкновении и максимальное значение сохраняется в объекте `state` для анализа.

Проводил испытания с одним `Rigidbody2D+Collider2D`(мяч). При падении с одной высоты значение постоянное. Когда роняю свое тело, там сила удара каждый раз разная выходит. Подозреваю что при ударе пружины от связанных объектов заставляют объект терять часть энергии и скорость после удара за счет этого падает.

Если усложнить испытания и сделать падение с начальным ускорением в сторону и ударами с отскоком от боковой поверхности то после падения на пол значение отклоняются еще больше и уже даже у мяча нет стабильности в полученном значении.

В думках каким образом стабильно определять на сколько сильно повреждение после падения? Может у кого есть опыт в решении подобных задач, или хотя бы идеи как произвести расчет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решение было выбрано следующее:
У объекта расчет скорости с которой тело сталкивается с поверхностью выполнялось за несколько шагов. Пока тело падает до удара  следим за скоростью. Когда зафиксировано касание к поверхности за несколько кадров определяем на сколько погасла скорость относительно скорости в полете. По истечении нескольких итераций либо когда контакт с поверхностью прервался считаем на сколько была погашена скорость, и от нее уже рассчитываем силу воздействия.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не делать это просто умножая скорость падающего обьекта в момент удара на массу падающего обьекта?

Так же нужно будет мерять скорость по вполне конкретной координате (в зависимости от стороны удара)

Фактически будет стабильное значение в результате.

Comment: Сложность в том, что каждый раз при ударе скорость разная, видимо из за того что в момент удара на тело действует помимо гравитации еще и сила пружины.